# Is there any forcing free proof for hard independence results?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

We are forced to use forcing for almost all "hard" independence results such as: $Con(ZFC)\longrightarrow Con (ZFC+\neg CH) $. The question simply is:

**Primary Question:** Is there any "forcing free" proof for $Con(ZFC)\longrightarrow Con (ZFC+\neg CH) $ or $Con(ZF)\longrightarrow Con (ZF+\neg AC) $ or any other "hard" independence results?

**Secondary Question:** Please list all "non simple" consistency results which have two proofs one by forcing and another without using it.

Comment: [Related](http://mathoverflow.net/q/38727/6085).

Comment: No, there are no forcing-free proofs of any of these results. It would be great to come upon such a new technique. There are, of course, a few independent results that do not rely on forcing, but I do not know i they are of the kind you are seeking. There is the consistency of Aczel's anti-doundation axiom, for example. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/434074/462).

Comment: I thought I heard that Moschovakis has a proof of independence of V=L by omitting ordinals, rather than by forcing.

Comment: In Fraenkel atoms model AC fails.

Comment: @Eran And we have atoms, so we do not have extensionality, and the underlying theory is not $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: Moschovakis tells me he has no such result. The topic came up at UCLA some years ago where I had passed on Lawvere's claim that all such independence proofs were done by forcing and people were avid to prove it wrong (I hasten to add I never thought this was original to Lawvere, and I thought it was uncontroversial). But either the suggestions I got there, or my memory of them are wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Krivine realizability can be used to obtain independence results over $\mathsf{ZF}$. For instance, in Krivine's paper *[Realizability algebras II : new models of ZF + DC](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~krivine/articles/R_ZF.pdf)*, Logical Methods in Computer Science 8 (1:10) p. 1-28 (2012), he constructs a realizability model in which $\mathsf{AC}$ fails in a pretty strong way: there is an infinite sequence of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ strictly decreasing in cardinality.

Comment: This is nice! It is perhaps too soon to see whether we can get new results this way, but it has potential. Krivine says that forcing posets are a particular case of  realizability algebras, and there are some similarities, but to me the flavor of this approach is different.

Comment: The fear is that this ends up as "sheaf forcing", as studied by Xavier Caicedo and his students, see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.5854.pdf) for an example. We also have here a more general framework than forcing and unfortunately no new independence results yet.